# Avoiding entitized characters when using FOR XML PATH for string concatenation

Tags: sql-server, xml, concat

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    f1.CourseEventKey,
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT
                '; ' + Title
            FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    ces.CourseEventKey,
                    f.Title
                FROM
                    CourseEventSchedule ces
                INNER JOIN Facility f 
                    ON f.FacilityKey = ces.FacilityKey
                WHERE
                    ces.CourseEventKey IN 
                    (
                        SELECT CourseEventKey
                        FROM @CourseEvents
                    )
            ) f2
            WHERE
                f2.CourseEventKey = f1.CourseEventKey
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    , 1, 2, '')
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ces.CourseEventKey,
        f.Title
    FROM
        CourseEventSchedule ces
    INNER JOIN Facility f 
        ON f.FacilityKey = ces.FacilityKey
    WHERE
        ces.CourseEventKey IN 
        (
            SELECT CourseEventKey
            FROM @CourseEvents
        )
) f1;
```

It produces this result set:

```
CourseEventKey Titles
-------------- ----------------------------------
29             Test Facility 1
30             Memphis Training Room
32             Drury Inn &amp; Suites Creve Coeur
```

The data is accurate, but I can't have `FOR XML PATH('')` because it escapes certain special characters.

To be clear, I'm using `FOR XML PATH('')` because it is possible for records with the same `CourseEventKey` to have multiple `Facility` titles associated with them.

How can I retain the data returned by this query without using `FOR XML PATH('')`?

Comment: String concatenation like this won't ever be pretty.  Can't you do it in your app?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is going to be part of a stored procedure for a report, and I have very limited control over what that report does. It works well but the ONLY issue is the escaping of special characters. @JNK

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try changing you statement to match this:

```
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
```

This uses the [`.value xml` method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to solve your entitization problem.